# Equation caption format: Strange parenthesis?

Tags: equations, amsmath, brackets

I used a command to change the font family of my equation number, but it only affected the right parenthesis. The left one didn't change. What is going on? How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
     \renewcommand{\theequation}{\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries\Alph{equation}} 

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

**Example of error:**
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? The opening parenthesis is normal, and the closing parenthesis is boldface?

Comment: And what do you want, exactly?

Comment: you have `(\theequation)` so if you put a font change in `\theequation` then it will naturally only apply on one side (but you shouldn't put formatting in `\thezzz` counter macros.

Comment: Ok - but is there now a better way to change the font of equation caption?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most correct way of doing this, but...

[image]

The macro that holds the format of the equation tag is `\maketag@@@`. The standard definition is `\hbox {\m@th \normalfont #1}`, where `#1` is `(\theequation)`.

Adapting it to your example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{\hbox {\m@th \sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries #1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here it is, with the `\newtagform` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Alph{equation}}
\newtagform{sans}{\sffamily\bfseries\footnotesize(})

\begin{document}

\usetagform{sans}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]